# How to define relations using primary keys instead of entities in TypeORM WIth NestJS

Tags: orm, nestjs, typeorm, circular-dependency, one-to-one

I'm using NestJS + TypeORM, and have two entities that looks like follows:

```
export class User {
    @PrimaryColumn()
    UserID: number;

    @Column()
    UserName: string;

    @OneToOne(() => Blog)
    @JoinColumn()
    Blog: Blog;
}

export class Blog {
    @PrimaryColumn()
    BlogID: number;
    
    @Column()
    BlogName: string;
}
```

When a consumer sends a request to create a User like the following, with the BlogID in the request:

```
 userRequest = {
    "UserID": 1,
    "UserName": "me",
    "BlogID": 12
 }
```

On the backend, I can't do userRepository.create(userRequest), I'll have to convert the BlogID sent in the request to an actual Blog entity object so that typeorm can process this. Now, the only way I can think of doing this is my injecting the Blog repository and doing:

```
userEntity = {
  "UserID": userRequest.UserID
  "UserName": userRequest.UserName
  "Blog": await this.blogRepository.findOneBy({
      BlogID: userRequest.BlogID
    })
```

and finally doing:

```
userRepository.create(userEntity)
```

My main question: is there a way to do this without injecting the Blog repository into the User service? The problem that arises is that I also implement a functionality that requires me to inject the User repository into the Blog service, which creates a circular dependency. NestJS mandates that circular dependencies should be avoided at all costs, but I don't believe I'm trying to do anything that's programmatically bad practice by implementing this. If I could implement this without introducing a circular dependency, I would. And I believe the main thing that's stopping me from doing so is the fact that I need to import the repository of the entity into the service of the adjacent service. Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

```
userEntity = {
  "UserID": userRequest.UserID
  "UserName": userRequest.UserName
  "Blog": {id: userRequest.BlogId}
}
```

pass userRequest.BlogId as userEntity.Blog.id

Comment: I like the idea, I haven't thought of that before. The problem here is that I have multiple non-nullable fields in a Blog entity, so the compiler will complain if I try to just pass the primary key when other fields are also needed to conform to the entity class.

Answer (score 0):

Update your relation like this :

@OneToOne(() => Blog)

**@JoinColumn({ name: "blogId" })**

Blog: Blog;